# Activity Indicator before DisplayAlert

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a content page that sends an email over an SMTP server in my Xamarin app.

On clicking the submit button to send the email, the app does nothing but waits. During this wait, I want to show an activity indicator or a Label of text loading, so the user knows something is working before showing a DisplayAlert that the process was successful.

For one reason or the other, the ActivityIndicator, and Label Text is not showing.
Maybe am doing something wrong.

XAML

```
<StackLayout x:Name="myPop" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="#C0808080" Padding="5">

    <ContentView x:Name="input_box_overlay" 
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" 
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
    Padding="5">

        <StackLayout Padding="20" BackgroundColor="White" 
                     HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                     HeightRequest="230" WidthRequest="230">
            <Label Text="Enter suggestion" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"/>

            <StackLayout Padding="0, 10, 0, 0">
                <Editor x:Name="user_text" HeightRequest="100" Keyboard="Chat" BackgroundColor="#f7f8f9"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Submitting..." x:Name="load"/>
                <ActivityIndicator x:Name="indicator"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Button TextColor="White" Text="Cancel" Clicked="Cancel_Clicked" BackgroundColor="#C0808080"/>
                <Button TextColor="White" Text="Submit" Clicked="Submit_Clicked" BackgroundColor="#395368" />
            </StackLayout>


        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>

</StackLayout>
```

Code for the `Submit_Clicked` method/event

```
private async void Submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       indicator.IsRunning = true;
       indicator.IsVisible = true;
       indicator.IsEnabled = true;
       load.IsVisible = true;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("email@domain.com");
        mail.To.Add("email@domain.com");
        mail.Subject = "Subject";
        mail.Body = user_msg;
        SmtpServer.Port = 25;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sendemail, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        };
        SmtpServer.SendCompleted += (s, ev) => {
            indicator.IsRunning = false;
            indicator.IsVisible = false;
            indicator.IsEnabled = false;
            load.IsVisible = false;
        };
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);                        


        await DisplayAlert("Success", "Message Sent. Thank you.", "Ok");

        myPop.IsVisible = false;
        myPop.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Something went wrong. Please try again.", "ok");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `SmtpServer` have `Task SendAsync`?

Comment: Also, did you try using a custom renderer for this which works with native loading mechanism?

Comment: By ignoring the web server calling, try to test if those two views are showing normally by default or not.

Comment: @Nkosi yes, it does

Comment: @G.hakim custom renderer? I'm not sure I know what that is. I'm going to search and read about that.

Comment: @Vahid I tested that and the two views are showing normally.

Comment: I will share my loader code in sometime i have a custom renderer for the same

Comment: @G.hakim Okay. I'll look forward to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider keeping the code async and not making it block the UI, which is what would happen with `SmtpClient.Send`

This is a refactoring of the original code provided to allow for a non-blocking flow

```cs
private async void Submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        ToggleIndicator(true);
        await SendEmailAsync();
        ToggleIndicator(false);
        await DisplayAlert("Success", "Message Sent. Thank you.", "Ok");
        myPop.IsVisible = false;
        myPop.IsEnabled = false;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Something went wrong. Please try again.", "ok");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void ToggleIndicator(bool show) {
    indicator.IsRunning = show;
    indicator.IsVisible = show;
    indicator.IsEnabled = show;
    load.IsVisible = show;
}

private async Task SendEmailAsync() {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("email@domain.com");
    mail.To.Add("email@domain.com");
    mail.Subject = "Subject";
    mail.Body = user_msg;
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net");
    SmtpServer.Port = 25;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sendemail, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
        return true;
    };
    await SmtpServer.SendMailAsync(mail);
}
```

While the XAML looks OK, I would also assume that the label and indicator visibility would be false initially

```xml
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Label Text="Submitting..." x:Name="load" IsVisible="False"/>
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="indicator" IsVisible="False"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I really love your approach. It appears I can't use SendAsync for SmtpServer like you did. To use SendAsync it requires I have more than one overload. What do you suggest ? The indicator is still not showing

Comment: @OluwasayoBabalola check update. Use [`Task SendMailAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly. I got the logic too. The method was running all through before and adding the await makes it  run asynchronously. Right?

Comment: @OluwasayoBabalola that is correct. It pushes the blocking code to another thread to allow the UI to stay responsive.

Comment: Great. Thank you :)